# Bell numbers proof

Tags: combinatorics, equivalence-relations, bell-numbers

Let $p(n)$ denote the number of different equivalence
relations on a set with $n$ elements (The number of partitions of a set with $n$ elements).
Show that $p(n)$ satisfies the recurrence relation

$$p(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}jp(n-j-1)$$

and the initial
condition $p(0) = 1$. (Note: The numbers $p(n)$ are called
Bell numbers after the American mathematician E. T.
Bell.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element $n$ must be in some part of the partition. Of the remaining $n - 1$ elements, suppose $j$ of them are in the same part as element $n$. The number of ways in which this can occur is $\binom{n-1}j$. The number of ways of partitioning the rest of the elements is $p(n - j - 1)$. Multiply those together and sum over $j$.